# How to run Jquery on click of an ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I run jquery when an MVC ActionLink is clicked? I have an action that takes some time. I want to show a 'processing' image until it returns. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using the Html.ActionLink or Ajax.ActionLink ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the actionlink a class:

```
@Html.ActionLink("","", new { @class:"delete" })
```

Then you can hook up your jQuery to the class name in a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete').click(function() {
    ///Code
  });
});
```

You can also work with `id`.

Comment: I used mine to get a confirm window before deleting something

Comment: For reference, had to use the ActionLink method signature that specified the controller. So, it looked more like this: Html.ActionLink("Process Billing", "ProcessBilling", "IndividualController",new {@class= "process" })

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `@Ajax.ActionLink` without need of jQuery script.
For example you can show a div when loading a page.

```
<div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link name", "Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loadingId", UpdateTargetId = "MyDataTable" })
</div>

<div id="loadingId" style="display:none; color:Red; font-weight: bold">
<p>Please wait...</p>
</div>

<div id = "MyData" class="tablediv">
    <table id = "MyDataTable" class="Grid">
        <tbody id="chartdata">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element-id').live('click', function(e) {
   //do stuff here ...
});
```

The trick is to give your action link an ID HTML attribute so you can use it as your element id:

```
$('#html-attribute-id').live('click', function(e) {
   //do stuff here ...
});
```